# network connection on kali

Tags: debian, networkmanager

I have installed Kaliv2 64bit (all packages updated) on vmware and I want to connect to internet with usb wlan (tp-link wn722nn) so I don't use *virtual vmware network* and just connect directly to my usb wlan (*removable devices*) but:

1. I can not find any network icon in the top panel like the depicted picture

   [image]

   [image]

   I tried to reinstall network manager but nothing happened

   ```
   sudo apt-get install -d --reinstall network-manager network-manager-gnome
   sudo apt-get install wicd-gtk
   sudo apt-get remove network-manager-gnome network-manager
   ```

   then reboot it ]
2. I have connected to internet like below but whenever I reboot the os I should do it again to be able using internet

   ```
   ip link set wlan0 up
   iw wlan0 link
   iw wlan0 scan
   wpa_passphrase ssid-name  >> /etc/wpa_supplicant.conf
   wpa_supplicant -B -D wext -i wlan0 -c /etc/wpa_supplicant.conf
   dhclient wlan0
   sudo /etc/init.d/samba stop
   sudo /etc/init.d/samba start
   ```

PS. my kali used to worked correctly !!
dmesg output for usb

```
    Line 1499: [    1.204511] ACPI: bus type USB registered
    Line 1500: [    1.204534] usbcore: registered new interface driver usbfs
    Line 1500: [    1.204534] usbcore: registered new interface driver usbfs
    Line 1501: [    1.204542] usbcore: registered new interface driver hub
    Line 1502: [    1.204593] usbcore: registered new device driver usb
    Line 1502: [    1.204593] usbcore: registered new device driver usb
    Line 1503: [    1.205082] ehci_hcd: USB 2.0 'Enhanced' Host Controller (EHCI) Driver
    Line 1507: [    1.212797] uhci_hcd: USB Universal Host Controller Interface driver
    Line 1574: [    1.236127] uhci_hcd 0000:02:00.0: new USB bus registered, assigned bus number 1
    Line 1577: [    1.236659] usb usb1: New USB device found, idVendor=1d6b, idProduct=0001
    Line 1577: [    1.236659] usb usb1: New USB device found, idVendor=1d6b, idProduct=0001
    Line 1577: [    1.236659] usb usb1: New USB device found, idVendor=1d6b, idProduct=0001
    Line 1578: [    1.236661] usb usb1: New USB device strings: Mfr=3, Product=2, SerialNumber=1
    Line 1578: [    1.236661] usb usb1: New USB device strings: Mfr=3, Product=2, SerialNumber=1
    Line 1578: [    1.236661] usb usb1: New USB device strings: Mfr=3, Product=2, SerialNumber=1
    Line 1579: [    1.236662] usb usb1: Product: UHCI Host Controller
    Line 1579: [    1.236662] usb usb1: Product: UHCI Host Controller
    Line 1580: [    1.236663] usb usb1: Manufacturer: Linux 4.0.0-kali1-amd64 uhci_hcd
    Line 1580: [    1.236663] usb usb1: Manufacturer: Linux 4.0.0-kali1-amd64 uhci_hcd
    Line 1581: [    1.236664] usb usb1: SerialNumber: 0000:02:00.0
    Line 1581: [    1.236664] usb usb1: SerialNumber: 0000:02:00.0
    Line 1582: [    1.236891] hub 1-0:1.0: USB hub found
    Line 1590: [    1.548303] usb 1-1: new full-speed USB device number 2 using uhci_hcd
    Line 1590: [    1.548303] usb 1-1: new full-speed USB device number 2 using uhci_hcd
    Line 1642: [    1.604783] ehci-pci 0000:02:03.0: new USB bus registered, assigned bus number 2
    Line 1647: [    1.676125] ehci-pci 0000:02:03.0: USB 2.0 started, EHCI 1.00
    Line 1648: [    1.676217] usb usb2: New USB device found, idVendor=1d6b, idProduct=0002
    Line 1648: [    1.676217] usb usb2: New USB device found, idVendor=1d6b, idProduct=0002
    Line 1648: [    1.676217] usb usb2: New USB device found, idVendor=1d6b, idProduct=0002
    Line 1649: [    1.676219] usb usb2: New USB device strings: Mfr=3, Product=2, SerialNumber=1
    Line 1649: [    1.676219] usb usb2: New USB device strings: Mfr=3, Product=2, SerialNumber=1
    Line 1649: [    1.676219] usb usb2: New USB device strings: Mfr=3, Product=2, SerialNumber=1
    Line 1650: [    1.676220] usb usb2: Product: EHCI Host Controller
    Line 1650: [    1.676220] usb usb2: Product: EHCI Host Controller
    Line 1651: [    1.676221] usb usb2: Manufacturer: Linux 4.0.0-kali1-amd64 ehci_hcd
    Line 1651: [    1.676221] usb usb2: Manufacturer: Linux 4.0.0-kali1-amd64 ehci_hcd
    Line 1652: [    1.676222] usb usb2: SerialNumber: 0000:02:03.0
    Line 1652: [    1.676222] usb usb2: SerialNumber: 0000:02:03.0
    Line 1653: [    1.676370] hub 2-0:1.0: USB hub found
    Line 1655: [    1.695859] usb 1-1: New USB device found, idVendor=0e0f, idProduct=0003
    Line 1655: [    1.695859] usb 1-1: New USB device found, idVendor=0e0f, idProduct=0003
    Line 1656: [    1.695862] usb 1-1: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=0
    Line 1656: [    1.695862] usb 1-1: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=0
    Line 1657: [    1.695864] usb 1-1: Product: VMware Virtual USB Mouse
    Line 1657: [    1.695864] usb 1-1: Product: VMware Virtual USB Mouse
    Line 1658: [    1.695865] usb 1-1: Manufacturer: VMware
    Line 1660: [    1.705993] usbcore: registered new interface driver usbhid
    Line 1660: [    1.705993] usbcore: registered new interface driver usbhid
    Line 1661: [    1.705995] usbhid: USB HID core driver
    Line 1661: [    1.705995] usbhid: USB HID core driver
    Line 1662: [    1.706742] input: VMware VMware Virtual USB Mouse as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:11.0/0000:02:00.0/usb1/1-1/1-1:1.0/0003:0E0F:0003.0001/input/input2
    Line 1662: [    1.706742] input: VMware VMware Virtual USB Mouse as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:11.0/0000:02:00.0/usb1/1-1/1-1:1.0/0003:0E0F:0003.0001/input/input2
    Line 1663: [    1.706894] hid-generic 0003:0E0F:0003.0001: input,hidraw0: USB HID v1.10 Mouse [VMware VMware Virtual USB Mouse] on usb-0000:02:00.0-1/input0
    Line 1663: [    1.706894] hid-generic 0003:0E0F:0003.0001: input,hidraw0: USB HID v1.10 Mouse [VMware VMware Virtual USB Mouse] on usb-0000:02:00.0-1/input0
    Line 1663: [    1.706894] hid-generic 0003:0E0F:0003.0001: input,hidraw0: USB HID v1.10 Mouse [VMware VMware Virtual USB Mouse] on usb-0000:02:00.0-1/input0
    Line 1664: [    1.812396] usb 1-2: new full-speed USB device number 3 using uhci_hcd
    Line 1664: [    1.812396] usb 1-2: new full-speed USB device number 3 using uhci_hcd
    Line 1665: [    1.958291] usb 1-2: New USB device found, idVendor=0e0f, idProduct=0002
    Line 1665: [    1.958291] usb 1-2: New USB device found, idVendor=0e0f, idProduct=0002
    Line 1666: [    1.958294] usb 1-2: New USB device strings: Mfr=0, Product=1, SerialNumber=0
    Line 1666: [    1.958294] usb 1-2: New USB device strings: Mfr=0, Product=1, SerialNumber=0
    Line 1667: [    1.958295] usb 1-2: Product: VMware Virtual USB Hub
    Line 1667: [    1.958295] usb 1-2: Product: VMware Virtual USB Hub
    Line 1668: [    1.966265] hub 1-2:1.0: USB hub found
    Line 1670: [    2.263834] usb 1-2.1: new full-speed USB device number 4 using uhci_hcd
    Line 1670: [    2.263834] usb 1-2.1: new full-speed USB device number 4 using uhci_hcd
    Line 1671: [    2.382120] usb 1-2.1: New USB device found, idVendor=0e0f, idProduct=0008
    Line 1671: [    2.382120] usb 1-2.1: New USB device found, idVendor=0e0f, idProduct=0008
    Line 1672: [    2.382123] usb 1-2.1: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=3
    Line 1672: [    2.382123] usb 1-2.1: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=3
    Line 1673: [    2.382125] usb 1-2.1: Product: Virtual Bluetooth Adapter
    Line 1674: [    2.382126] usb 1-2.1: Manufacturer: VMware
    Line 1675: [    2.382127] usb 1-2.1: SerialNumber: 000650268328
    Line 1755: [   18.549451] usbcore: registered new interface driver btusb
    Line 1755: [   18.549451] usbcore: registered new interface driver btusb
    Line 1774: [   89.624309] usb 2-1: new high-speed USB device number 2 using ehci-pci
    Line 1774: [   89.624309] usb 2-1: new high-speed USB device number 2 using ehci-pci
    Line 1775: [   89.840913] usb 2-1: New USB device found, idVendor=0cf3, idProduct=9271
    Line 1775: [   89.840913] usb 2-1: New USB device found, idVendor=0cf3, idProduct=9271
    Line 1776: [   89.840917] usb 2-1: New USB device strings: Mfr=16, Product=32, SerialNumber=48
    Line 1776: [   89.840917] usb 2-1: New USB device strings: Mfr=16, Product=32, SerialNumber=48
    Line 1777: [   89.840919] usb 2-1: Product: USB2.0 WLAN
    Line 1777: [   89.840919] usb 2-1: Product: USB2.0 WLAN
    Line 1778: [   89.840920] usb 2-1: Manufacturer: ATHEROS
    Line 1779: [   89.840921] usb 2-1: SerialNumber: 12345
    Line 1792: [   91.401663] usb 2-1: ath9k_htc: Firmware htc_9271.fw requested
    Line 1793: [   91.402105] usbcore: registered new interface driver ath9k_htc
    Line 1794: [   91.423668] usb 2-1: firmware: direct-loading firmware htc_9271.fw
    Line 1795: [   91.727156] usb 2-1: ath9k_htc: Transferred FW: htc_9271.fw, size: 50980
```

interfaces output: (during my diagnose I added the lines for eth0 and wlan0 and then comment them)

```
# This file describes the network interfaces available on your system
# and how to activate them. For more information, see interfaces(5).

source /etc/network/interfaces.d/*

# The loopback network interface
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

# allow-hotplug eth0
# iface eth0 inet dhcp

# auto wlan0
# iface wlan0 inet dhcp
```

Comment: Line 1792, the pen is certainly there and being recognized.

Comment: what is the content of your /etc/network/interfaces?

Comment: I edited my post Rui.

Comment: please uncomment the last two lines, and do /etc/init.d/networking restart

Comment: I did it -> [ ok ] Restarting networking (via systemctl): networking.service. but when I ping it says connect: Network is unreachable

Comment: go to network manager now.

Comment: there isn't any network manager as gui ;(

Comment: do not comment them back....you will be needing them active in the future. I would say the only thing missing is making sure that wpa_supplicant goes up upon booting, but I can be wrong.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/31755/discussion-between-mohammad-yousefi-and-rui-f-ribeiro).

Comment: try reinstalling thoses pkgs " `apt-get install --reinstall network-manager firmware-ralink` "

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We reached to the conclusion that uncommenting the `wlan0` and adding a directive to run the wpa_supplicant, worked. Please note that having dhcp in the interface already makes the dhclient invocation.

```
auto wlan0
iface wlan0 inet dhcp
    wpa-conf /etc/wpa_supplicant.conf
```

Answer (score 0):

I gave you the technically correct answer, and as usual I have got a "better answer", the questions you should have asked.

Using kali, I would venture to say it is not the best idea to use that pen for Internet. You would use the ethernet of the VM (eth0) to have internet (it does not matter whether the real machine has eth0 or wifi, eth0 in the VM will use the Internet connection)...and that pen you have will be of far better use either to manufacture packets or as hostap to attract PCs to connect to it. After all, that is probably why you bought a special pen like that for Kali.

I will leave to you as an exercise to configure eth0 and bridge or NAT in vmware.

Regards