# Connect Automatically to network with authentication Without Encryption on BeagleBone Black

Tags: debian, wifi, usb, network-interface

I develop a project in which using BeagleBone Black board with Debian, in which I need connect the board automatically to open networks detected via WIFI (authentication Without Encryption) when the board is start.
Actually [I configure manually by command lines](https://learn.sparkfun.com/tutorials/using-pcduinos-wifi-dongle-with-the-pi?_ga=1.156208317.788097784.1447878629), but this isn't useful as I need configure the interface manually every time to connect the board to network.

Comment: please have a look at http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/243845/network-connection-on-kali

Comment: Thank's for your answer, I read the other post and I see he used 
"wpa_supplicant.conf" file and I find this article [link](https://wiki.debian.org/WiFi/HowToUse) where it explained how to use Wifi Configuration in debian.

Comment: Yes, it is the standard way of doing it using wifi as a client. enjoy it.