# Install wireless usb on CentOS 7 (VMWare)

Tags: centos, wifi, usb, vmware

I have installed CentOS 7 on a virtual machine using a windows host.

I am wanting to install my USB wifi dongle so it can be used on the CentOS 7 guest. (My windows does not use this dongle)

I know the driver needed is the RT2870 but i am unsure where to go from here.

Comment: duplicate of http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/243845/network-connection-on-kali?noredirect=1#comment418619_243845

Comment: That tells me nothing of what i need to know.

Comment: The you would better read it again, speacilly the part about editing /etc/network/interfaces, and about reading dmesg to see the interfaces of the USB and the named of the device coming up.

Comment: /etc/network/ is not a directory.

Comment: Sorry my fault. The others instructions are for Debian. Have a look at network manager.